# What is the difference between Flutter Android Embedding V1 and V2

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-android, android-embedded-api

I am working on a plugin for Flutter with background stuff.
Recently, I faced somethings about **Flutter android embedding** in the [android_alarm_manager](https://pub.dev/packages/android_alarm_manager) plugin.

A part of the `README` says:

> For the Flutter Android Embedding V1, the background service must be provided a callback to register plugins with the background isolate.

- What exactly is **Flutter android embedding** V1 or V2?
- What are the differences between these two?

Comment: Flutter project leser that 1.12 having V1 and from 1.12 with new V2 Android platform-side wrappers. https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Upgrading-pre-1.12-Android-projects

Answer (score 5):

According to [docs](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Upgrading-pre-1.12-Android-projects):

> In order to better support the execution environments of adding Flutter to an existing project, the old Android platform-side wrappers hosting the Flutter runtime at io.flutter.app.FlutterActivity and their associated classes are now deprecated. New wrappers at io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity and associated classes now replace them.

Those classes better support real world scenarios where the FlutterActivity isn't the first and only Android Activity in an application.

The embedded v2 provides better support for things like background execution (firebase messaging for instance. Checkout the [changeLog](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging#604)).

If you are developing a plugin, you should consider starting with embedded v2. Existing packages are already migrated or migrating.